# Two $1×1$ squares are chosen at random on $4×4$ grid , What is the probability that they are not adjacent?

Tags: probability

> Two  distinct  $1×1$ squares are chosen at random on $4×4$  grid  , What is the probability that they are not adjacent ?
>   choices :-
>
> (a) $3/10$
>
> (b)$1/2$
>
> (c) $7/10$
>
> (d) $9/10$

My try follows

Number of 1×1 adjacent squares $= 3×(4+4)=24$

Number of ways to choses 1×1 square  $=16C2=120$

P(they are adjacent)$= 24/120=1/5$

P (they are not adjacent)  = $ 1- 1/5=4/5=8/10$

> But the answer in the book is  $9/10$

I don't know why the answer is $9/10$

please help me understanding  what's wrong in my answer
Thank you for your help

Comment: Two *distinct* squares are chosen?

Comment: The problem  said just two squares;  with no extra  details

Comment: The number if 1 x 1 adjacent squares that you calculated is wrong. Try again or ask me I will tell you.

Comment: @Reeshabh Ranjan  Ok ; i ask you ; tell me please

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan  Drawing the picture seems like 24 is the correct number of adjacent pairs; what are you getting?

Comment: Indeed, @ThomasGrubb, that's what I found, as well. $24$ possible cases in which there $2$ adjacent squares.

Comment: It's a very baldy worded question. First, not clear whether choices have to be distinct or whether the same square can be chosen twice. Secondly, not clear what counts as "adjacent" are diagonal neighbours "adjacent" or not ? If we assume distinct choices and diagonal neighbours are *not* adjacent then I get 8/10.

Comment: @gandalf61  i think  they are distinct  ; and i wonder if diagonal squares  are considered adjacent  or not

Comment: @gandalf61  I think you are pulling hairs here.  $24/120 = 8/10.$ If diagonals adjacencies count, the numerator would increase to $42/120$, or 3.5/10 which is not even an option further away from $9/10$. And adjacency is a relation between positioning of two objects.

Comment: See my comment above, prayer smith.  There are $18$ ways in which two tiles can be adjacent diagonaly.

Comment: @amWhy Yes - I don't disagree with 24 adjacent pairs. I just think the original question, wherever it came from, is poorly worded. 8/10 isn't an answer option, and I cannot see any interpretation of the questions which gives an answer of 9/10.

Comment: I agree; I don't blame the asker, though.  This may be the work of a bad editor of the textbook, and throw in a mistyped answer option, etc. And it creates a confused student, who has made no error in his/her work, and frustrated users who want to help said student.

Comment: prayer smith, What is the name of the text-book you are using, and its author.  Now days, many textbooks (on or off line) - or the publishers of the same, have websites where they maintain  errata for the given text.  This problem may be listed there, but if it isn't yet, notify your instructor and ask her/him to submit the error to the publisher.  (You may even be able to submit this yourself on the publishers'/editor's website.)

Comment: @prayersmith Sorry for creating confusion. Now I know where I was doing mistake. So yeah, the answer should be 8/10 in that case, imo.

Comment: @prayersmith I wanted to share another method for doing such questions involving grids and chessboards. http://prntscr.com/f09r15 This is the answer to this question which I immediately deleted as I realised I was overcounting some squares. Although my answer is wrong, my method may come handy to you in case of, for example, counting squares which form an 'L' shape.

Comment: @Reeshabh Ranjan  Thank you for your help  ; Excellent  work

Answer (score 2):

> Number of 1×1 adjacent squares $= 3×(4+4)=24$
>
> Number of ways to choses 1×1 square  $=16C2=120$
>
> P(they are adjacent)$= 24/120=1/5$
>
> P (they are not adjacent)  = $ 1- 1/5=4/5=8/10$

I don't see a mistake, but perhaps I'm missing it too.

I assume you have to take *distinct squares* (adjacent wouldn't make much sense when picking the same tile twice) and adjacent as being only attached vertically or horizontally, not diagonally.

Alternatively, note that there are:

- 4 *corner* tiles with 2 adjacent tiles each;
- 8 (non-corner) *side* tiles with 3 adjacent tiles each;
- 4 *internal* tiles with 4 adjacent tiles each.

Taking order into account, we can find the probability of picking an adjacent tile after a first tile was picked out of these three categories. The complement is the probability of non-adjacency. Note that the order of picking the tiles isn't relevant for this question, but since it simply doubles both the adjacent and non-adjacent cases, it provides a second method backing up your answer.

With the process of picking from above, the probability for non-adjacent sides is then also given by:
$$1 - \left( \frac{4}{16}\frac{2}{15}+\frac{8}{16}\frac{3}{15}+\frac{4}{16}\frac{4}{15} \right) = 1-\frac{1}{5}=\frac{4}{5}$$

Comment: @amWhy Yes, but we're leaving out the non-adjacent ones twice too - so for the probability it doesn't matter - I think?

Comment: I just see your counting (listing) 48 adjacencies is problematic and confusing, if you don't explain your method more carefully in the post.  I think the upper part of your post is fine, and you are not mistaken.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just noticed that I clearly missed a dollar sign in my first comment here!

Comment: @amWhy I get the confusion. With this listing, you find the probability if you take the _order_ (of picking) into account. The order obviously doesn't matter, but it doesn't change the probability since accounting for order simply doubles both the adjacent **and** the non-adjacent cases. Adding this alternative was meant as a back-up to OP's calculation, as a sort of confirmation...

Comment: Not sure if it's getting any clearer, but I added a part to address the possible confusion of the double counting.

Comment: StackTD You have made it clearer.  I knew what you were trying to do; simply hoped you clarify in your post what you were doing.  Thanks!